# Why am I getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array" when running mstest.exe on the commandline?

Tags: exception, mstest

I am running this on my machine

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" /testcontainer:"C:\Working\Einstein\Solutions\EinsteinAcceptanceTests\bin\Debug\EinsteinAcceptanceTests.dll" /resultsfile:TestResult.trx"
```

And I get

> index was outside the bounds of the array

message back.

Any clue on how to debug this?

Comment: how did you build the test assembly?

Comment: Does it work with Visual Studio?

Comment: Can you show your test method and of the code under test?

Comment: I have similar problem, Did you manage to solve it? If Yes, How ?

Comment: I believe it would have been version incompatibility.  Please check you are running the correct version of visual studio that the tests were written.  If you find nothing I'd suggest writing the existing tests in your current version of VS that do work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check for version incompatibility. E.g. you get this error when trying to run VS2008 Tests with VS2010 mstest.exe.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me in VS 2012, the problem being that I had 2 unit test projects referencing to different versions of the assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework'

I saw the problem when compiling the solution, in the output window from the test section:

------ Discover test started ------ 
index was outside the bounds of the array